# Cabal doesn't rebuild project after c header file change

Tags: haskell, cabal

In my `project.cabal` file, I have:

```
cabal-version:       >=1.10

name:                inlinewrappers
version:             0.1.0.0

build-type:          Simple
extra-source-files:  CHANGELOG.md

executable inlinewrappers
  main-is:             Main.hs

  build-depends:       base >=4.14 && <4.15
                     , inline-c

  extra-libraries:     gsl
  include-dirs:        cbits
  includes:            hello.h

  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I'm hoping that `cabal` to rebuild my project after I made modifications to the `hello.h` header file.

Is there a cabal flag that I can turn on?

Comment: Possibly relevant: [`addDependentFile`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/template-haskell-2.17.0.0/docs/Language-Haskell-TH-Syntax.html#v:addDependentFile) (but see also [this cabal issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/4746)).

Comment: I'm getting the same thing for `cxx-sources: help.cpp`

Answer (score 0):

As the comments indicate, there is no way to do this currently, though there is an open ticket in `cabal` to improve the situation.